# Scrapy Deny rules

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

Hey I'm currently using scrapy and have noticed when running a crawl that my deny rules are being completely ignored leading to multiple scrapes of the same items is anyone able to tell me why. Any help is appreciated

```
class DIY_spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'diy_cat'
    allowed_domains = ['diy.com']

    start_urls =[
        #"http://www.diy.com",
        "http://www.diy.com/nav/decor",
        "http://www.diy.com/nav/garden",
        "http://www.diy.com/nav/rooms",
        "http://www.diy.com/nav/fix",
        "http://www.diy.com/nav/build",

    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'/nav/decor|garden|rooms|fix|build/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)$'),
                               deny=('//diy/jsp/',
                                     'pricerange',
                                     'productId',
                                     '-size%',
                                     'tab=rev')),follow=True),

        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'/nav/decor|garden|rooms|fix|build/(.*)[0-9]{8}$' ),)
             , follow=True, callback='parse_items'),
```

**************************Edit*********************************

here is whats happening from the log

2014-04-07 15:01:47+0100 [diy_cat] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.diy.com/nav/garden/garden-buildings/cabins-summerhouses/-constructiontype-Interlocking/-pricerangec-1200-1300/-size%3E3_29_x_2_39m/Shire-11x8-Berryfield-Log-Cabin-Home-Delivered-Only-13538712?height=411&mediaId=m8416757&productId=13538712&skuId=14009418&width=411>

```
{'currency_code': 'GBP',
 'supplier_name': 'www.diy.com',
 'supplier_part_description': u'19mm tongue and groove interlocking timber to side walls, 12mm tongue and groove timber to floor and roof, supplied with pressure treated floor joists and green roofing felt.',
 'supplier_part_name': u'Shire 11x8 Berryfield Log Cabin - Home Delivered Only',
 'supplier_part_number': u'5019804112289',
 'supplier_price_gross': 1249.98,
 'supplier_price_net': 1041.65,
 'supplier_price_tax_amount': 208.33,
 'supplier_url': 'http://www.diy.com/nav/garden/garden-buildings/cabins-summerhouses/-constructiontype-Interlocking/-pricerangec-1200-1300/-size%3E3_29_x_2_39m/Shire-11x8-Berryfield-Log-Cabin-Home-Delivered-Only-13538712'}
```

2014-04-07 15:01:47+0100 [diy_cat] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.diy.com/nav/garden/garden-buildings/cabins-summerhouses/-constructiontype-Interlocking/-pricerangec-1200-1300/-size%3E3_29_x_2_39m/Shire-11x8-Berryfield-Log-Cabin-Home-Delivered-Only-13538712?height=411&mediaId=m8416844&productId=13538712&skuId=14009418&width=411>

```
{'currency_code': 'GBP',
 'supplier_name': 'www.diy.com',
 'supplier_part_description': u'19mm tongue and groove interlocking timber to side walls, 12mm tongue and groove timber to floor and roof, supplied with pressure treated floor joists and green roofing felt.',
 'supplier_part_name': u'Shire 11x8 Berryfield Log Cabin - Home Delivered Only',
 'supplier_part_number': u'5019804112289',
 'supplier_price_gross': 1249.98,
 'supplier_price_net': 1041.65,
 'supplier_price_tax_amount': 208.33,
 'supplier_url': 'http://www.diy.com/nav/garden/garden-buildings/cabins-summerhouses/-constructiontype-Interlocking/-pricerangec-1200-1300/-size%3E3_29_x_2_39m/Shire-11x8-Berryfield-Log-Cabin-Home-Delivered-Only-13538712'}
```

2014-04-07 15:01:47+0100 [diy_cat] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.diy.com/nav/garden/garden-buildings/cabins-summerhouses/-constructiontype-Interlocking/-pricerangec-1200-1300/-size%3E3_29_x_2_39m/Shire-11x8-Berryfield-Log-Cabin-Home-Delivered-Only-13538712?height=411&mediaId=m8417696&productId=13538712&skuId=14009418&width=411>

```
{'currency_code': 'GBP',
 'supplier_name': 'www.diy.com',
 'supplier_part_description': u'19mm tongue and groove interlocking timber to side walls, 12mm tongue and groove timber to floor and roof, supplied with pressure treated floor joists and green roofing felt.',
 'supplier_part_name': u'Shire 11x8 Berryfield Log Cabin - Home Delivered Only',
 'supplier_part_number': u'5019804112289',
 'supplier_price_gross': 1249.98,
 'supplier_price_net': 1041.65,
 'supplier_price_tax_amount': 208.33,
 'supplier_url': 'http://www.diy.com/nav/garden/garden-buildings/cabins-summerhouses/-constructiontype-Interlocking/-pricerangec-1200-1300/-size%3E3_29_x_2_39m/Shire-11x8-Berryfield-Log-Cabin-Home-Delivered-Only-13538712'}
```

2014-04-07 15:01:47+0100 [diy_cat] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.diy.com/nav/garden/garden-buildings/cabins-summerhouses/-constructiontype-Interlocking/-pricerangec-1200-1300/-size%3E3_29_x_2_39m/Shire-11x8-Berryfield-Log-Cabin-Home-Delivered-Only-13538712?heroPopup=true&mediaId=m8417696&productId=13538712&skuId=14009418>

```
{'currency_code': 'GBP',
 'supplier_name': 'www.diy.com',
 'supplier_part_description': u'19mm tongue and groove interlocking timber to side walls, 12mm tongue and groove timber to floor and roof, supplied with pressure treated floor joists and green roofing felt.',
 'supplier_part_name': u'Shire 11x8 Berryfield Log Cabin - Home Delivered Only',
 'supplier_part_number': u'5019804112289',
 'supplier_price_gross': 1249.98,
 'supplier_price_net': 1041.65,
 'supplier_price_tax_amount': 208.33,
 'supplier_url': 'http://www.diy.com/nav/garden/garden-buildings/cabins-summerhouses/-constructiontype-Interlocking/-pricerangec-1200-1300/-size%3E3_29_x_2_39m/Shire-11x8-Berryfield-Log-Cabin-Home-Delivered-Only-13538712'}
```

Comment: Why do you think they are not working? Could you provide an example url that should not be scraped?

Comment: when i read back over the log i noticed that the same things where being scraped but with different links this is the link that should be http://www.diy.com/nav/garden/garden-buildings/cabins-summerhouses/-constructiontype-Interlocking/-pricerangec-1200-1300/-size%3E3_29_x_2_39m/Shire-11x8-Berryfield-Log-Cabin-Home-Delivered-Only-13538712

Comment: Would it be possible to post your complete code for easier testing? :)

Answer (score 2):

Having tested out your spider and the rules, I believe your deny rules were not correctly specified (a missing comma or two) and more specifically the deny rule for "/diy/jsp/" wasn't quite right.

I ran the spider for about 10 seconds or so with the modified rules below and couldn't find any instances of "diy/jsp" in the logs so I think this is working. That said, it would be worth adding `mediaId` to the deny list since this URL parameter was the only major difference in the duplicate URLs posted above.

```
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'/nav/decor|garden|rooms|fix|build/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)$'),
                           deny=('\.\./\.\./diy/jsp/',
                                 'pricerange',
                                 'productId',
                                 '-size%',
                                 'tab=rev'),),follow=True),

    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'/nav/decor|garden|rooms|fix|build/(.*)[0-9]{8}$' ),)
         , follow=True, callback='parse_items'),
    )
```